# Download only certain lines from online .txt file

Tags: python, bash, pandas

Genome annotations are stored in large plain textfiles, e.g. https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ena/data/view/FO203355&display=textc

I want to extract only the lines starting with "FT". Since I need to extract the "FT" of thousands of these files, it would be unfeasible to download the whole files and extract the needed lines manually.

Is there any terminal- or python construct to do this? I ultimately want to create a large (python) pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Since you ultimately intend to use `pandas`, all you need is to stream the data to your script and filter the lines you need. The easiest way is to use the `requests` module in streaming mode and then treat the remote data as a file stream, i.e.:

```
import requests

url = "https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ena/data/view/FO203355&display=text"

with requests.get(url, stream=True) as r:  # open a streaming request
    for line in r:  # iterate over the stream line by line
        if line[:2] == "FT":  # check if a line begins with `FT`
            print(line)  # or do whatever you want with the line
```

If you just want to save the data you can forward the filtered line to a file output stream:

```
import requests

url = "https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ena/data/view/FO203355&display=text"

with requests.get(url, stream=True) as r, open("output.dat", "w") as f:
    for line in r:  # iterate over the stream line by line
        if line[:2] == "FT":  # check if a line begins with `FT`
            f.write(line)  # write the line to output.dat
```

You may want to create your data frame and directly parse the line into it instead, however that depends on how you want to parse your data so that's an exercise I'll leave to you.

Answer (score -1):

You can use curl and grep. You still have to download the entire file, unless the ebi.ac.uk server api provides server side filtering.

```
curl 'https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ena/data/view/FO203355&display=text' | grep '^FT' > lines.txt
```